# Get a list of XML attribute values based off the existence of a child element (LINQ to XML)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Apologies on the first draft, I didn't realize I needed to mark the parts that were code, and thus they were dropped out leaving it to not make much sense. Fixed.

Here's a snippet from the XML which is using all attributes for dictating values. In the main XML, there are **many** `<L1Module>` elements, I've just copied 1 here. Some of them will have `<fee>` elements, some will not at all not even in the form `<fee/>`.

```
<L1Module moduleCode="CFINCEX-101" moduleTypeCode="OPTIONAL" moduleInstanceID="CFINCEX-101_906376" moduleTypeDescription="Optional" credits="0" quota="999" placesLeft="985">
<fees>
<fee feesCategory="STANDARD" feesDescription="Standard Category for Fees" feesAmount="10"/>
<fee feesCategory="STANDARD" feesDescription="Standard Category for Fees" feesAmount="86"/>
</fees>
<documents/>
<roles/>
<L2Modules/>
</L1Module>
```

Mostly what I need to to see if there's at least 1 `<fee>` element there or not in each `<L1Module>`. I'm cycling through the `<L1Module>`'s as such..

```
var elements = course_structureXML.Descendants("L1Module").Where(i => i.Value == "");
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
          check to see if there's a fee element
          if there is do something
          else do nothing
        }
```

I'm just having a hard time with seeing if there's a fee element. Should I even cycle through the `L1Module`s like this?

Hope that's a bit more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: "most examples out there are dealing with element values" means you can find some examples dealing with attributes

Comment: What do you mean by "L1Module elements *that have at least 1 element*"?  Do you mean *that have any child XML element*?  Or do you mean something more specific?

Comment: Ah sorry, L1Module elements that have at least 1 fee element.

Didn't know it would get cut out when I put brackets around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to figure out whether or not a L1Module element has fee elements inside of its fees element? The snippet below should point you in the right direction.

```
        String xmlWithFees = "<L1Module moduleCode=\"CFINCEX-101\" moduleTypeCode=\"OPTIONAL\" moduleInstanceID=\"CFINCEX-101_906376\" moduleTypeDescription=\"Optional\" credits=\"0\" quota=\"999\" placesLeft=\"985\">\n" +
                        "<fees>\n" +
                        "<fee feesCategory=\"STANDARD\" feesDescription=\"Standard Category for Fees\" feesAmount=\"10\"/>\n" +
                        "<fee feesCategory=\"STANDARD\" feesDescription=\"Standard Category for Fees\" feesAmount=\"86\"/>\n" +
                        "</fees>\n" +
                        "<documents/>\n" +
                        "<roles/>\n" +
                        "<L2Modules/>\n" +
                        "</L1Module>";

        String xmlWithoutFees = "<L1Module moduleCode=\"CFINCEX-101\" moduleTypeCode=\"OPTIONAL\" moduleInstanceID=\"CFINCEX-101_906376\" moduleTypeDescription=\"Optional\" credits=\"0\" quota=\"999\" placesLeft=\"985\">\n" +
            "<fees/>\n" +
            "<documents/>\n" +
            "<roles/>\n" +
            "<L2Modules/>\n" +
            "</L1Module>";

        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlWithFees);
        var l1module = document.Elements("L1Module").Where(el => el.HasElements);
        var fees = l1module.Elements("fees");
        bool hasFees = fees.Elements("fee").Any();
        // Will print true
        Console.WriteLine("Has fees? " + hasFees);

        document = XDocument.Parse(xmlWithoutFees);
        l1module = document.Elements("L1Module").Where(el => el.HasElements);
        fees = l1module.Elements("fees");
        hasFees = fees.Elements("fee").Any();
        // Will print false
        Console.WriteLine("Has fees? " + hasFees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean when you said "... has at least 1 element. This example has 2 ..." because that example has more than 2 elements. This should be enough to get you going though:

```
string xml = @"<L1Module moduleCode=""CFINCEX-101"" 
                         moduleTypeCode=""OPTIONAL"" 
                         moduleInstanceID=""CFINCEX-101_906376"" 
                         moduleTypeDescription=""Optional"" 
                         credits=""0"" 
                         quota=""999"" 
                         placesLeft=""985"">
                   <fees>
                       <fee feesCategory=""STANDARD"" 
                            feesDescription=""Standard Category for Fees""
                            feesAmount=""10""/>
                       <fee feesCategory=""STANDARD"" 
                            feesDescription=""Standard Category for Fees""
                            feesAmount=""86""/>
                   </fees>
                   <documents/>
                   <roles/>
                   <L2Modules/>
               </L1Module>";

var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var l1Modules = document.Elements("L1Module")
                        .Where(el => el.HasElements);

foreach (var l1module in l1Modules)
    Console.WriteLine(l1module.Attribute("moduleCode").Value);
```

Comment: Sorry, not only am I a LINQ noobie I'm also one on this site to and I didn't identify pieces of code in the description and they were removed. I re-edited it to hopefully make more sense.